# How to get labeled x-values to this Series graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, series

I am having trouble labeling the x ticks of a graph with the index values in the series `x` that I've created. Below is the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = pd.Series([421, 122, 275, 847, 175])
index_values = ['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-03', '2014-01-04',
               '2014-01-05']
x.index = index_values
x.plot()
plt.show()
```

This is the graph that is returned (without ticks on the x-axis):
[image: There are no markings on the x-axis]

So my question is: How do I label the x ticks with the dates in `index_values` (which are also the indexes in the Series `x`) ?

Comment: When I run your code, it does show the tick labels with the dates. Are you sure you're working with a recent version of matplotlib (now 3.1.1) and pandas (now  0.25.3)?

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. Just checked - I have version 3.0.2 of matplotlib and 0.23.4 of pandas. I guess I should try and update them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just updated and the tick labels are now visible

Answer (score 1):

You can set xticks directly through the following:

```
plt.xticks(x.index, index_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a label to the axis with the provided methods, as shown below:

```py
plt.ylabel('my Y label')
plt.xlabel('my X label')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Q is about x-ticks, not labels.